# Was "Men Without Bones" inspired by the Yara-ma-yha-who myth?

Tags: short-stories, inspiration

The story [*Men Without Bones*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Men_Without_Bones) by Gerald Kersh is very old and ends with the memorable line, "*We* are the Martians -- they are the men!"

According to legend the [Yara-ma-yha-who](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yara-ma-yha-who) is a:

> creature resembles a little red frog-like man with a very big head, a large mouth with no teeth and suckers on the ends of its hands and feet.

Was the story inspired by the legend?

Comment: I made a really big edit, because initially it didn't seem like you had a question at all. Please do [edit] this if I've overstepped, but can you make sure it stays as clear as possible.

Comment: The exact quotation from the story is "*Those boneless things are men. We are Martians!*"

Comment: I'm surprised they felt the need to invent a new Australian creature to frighten their children.

Comment: A cursory read through the wikipedia pages doesn't seem to indicate any particular similarity, except for being nocturnal. But many "monsters" are nocturnal.  Why do you speculate that the 1954 short story could be related to the native australian myth.

Comment: I think there are more similarities if you read the story itself.

Comment: @MishaR: I always thought the giant, carnivorous kangaroo would be very scary and truly dangerous.